# Problem when trying to use form control not part of input

Tags: html, css, angular, forms, angular-material

I am new at using the angular form, and I was told to use reactive forms and I am following the angular material tutorial, but when I tried to use the input that has the form control it says that is not part of the input, and I believe that I already have all the imports, here is the error my code.

`Can't bind to 'formControl' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.`

Html:

```
<label for="naame">Name: </label>
<input id="name" type="text" [formControl]="name">
```

Ts of the form component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form',
  templateUrl: './form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form.component.scss']
})
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {
  name = new FormControl('');
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

and also I have a module called material, where I have imported all the angular material stuff

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
// Material Form Controls
import { MatAutocompleteModule } from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatRadioModule } from '@angular/material/radio';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatSliderModule } from '@angular/material/slider';
import { MatSlideToggleModule } from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
// Material Navigation
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
// Material Layout
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatDividerModule } from '@angular/material/divider';
import { MatExpansionModule } from '@angular/material/expansion';
import { MatGridListModule } from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';
import { MatStepperModule } from '@angular/material/stepper';
import { MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material/tabs';
import { MatTreeModule } from '@angular/material/tree';
// Material Buttons & Indicators
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatButtonToggleModule } from '@angular/material/button-toggle';
import { MatBadgeModule } from '@angular/material/badge';
import { MatChipsModule } from '@angular/material/chips';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatProgressSpinnerModule } from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import { MatProgressBarModule } from '@angular/material/progress-bar';
import { MatRippleModule } from '@angular/material/core';
// Material Popups & Modals
import { MatBottomSheetModule } from '@angular/material/bottom-sheet';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatSnackBarModule } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material/tooltip';
// Material Data tables
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSortModule } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';

// import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
// import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material/core';

import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatTreeModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatBadgeModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    MatBottomSheetModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatTableModule,
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MaterialModule,

  ],
  exports: [
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatTreeModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatBadgeModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    MatBottomSheetModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatTableModule,
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MaterialModule,
  ]
})
export class MaterialModule { }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You have to import "ReactiveFormsModule"** in the module in which you have FormComponent, so please check that FormComponent is being declared in the same module you are importing ReactiveFormsModule, for example:

```
`import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
 import {FormComponent} from './FormComponent';

 @NgModule({
    declarations: [FormComponent],
    imports: [
       BrowserModule,
       FormsModule,
       ReactiveFormsModule,
       MaterialModule,
    ],
 })
 export class AppModule {}`
```

If this is not the case then the answer from Andres Blanco above should work for you.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use formControl you have to use it with a MatInput

```
<label for="name">Name: </label>
<input id="name" type="text" matInput [formControl]="name">
```

Comment: still not working